# Want to split name in cell after the middle initial not before it

Tags: excel, vba

'Here is the code I have but it is splitting the name before the middle initial and I need it to 'split after the middle initial.

```
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("C:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
On Error GoTo 0

 If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        v = Trim(c.Value)
          If InStr(v, " ") > 0 Then
            arr = Split(v, " ", 2)
            c.Resize(1, 2).Value = Array(arr(0), arr(1))
          End If
     Next c
 End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the split to remove the limit of 2 parts. Then I added an if else that checks how many parts you have after the split. If there are 3, it joins the middle part with the first part.

```vb
Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("C:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
On Error GoTo 0

 If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
    For Each c In Rng.Cells
        v = Trim(c.Value)
          If InStr(v, " ") > 0 Then
            arr = Split(v, " ")
            If UBound(arr) = 2 Then
                c.Resize(1, 2).Value = Array(arr(0) & " " & arr(1), arr(2))
            ElseIf UBound(arr) = 1 Then
                c.Resize(1, 2).Value = Array(arr(0), arr(1))
            Else
                arr = Split(v, " ", 2)
                c.Resize(1, 2).Value = Array(arr(0), arr(1))
            End If
          End If
     Next c
 End If
```

You may want to add an if/else statement to prevent other user-input related errors like what to do if `arr` is not an array after the split. Or if `Ubound(arr) = 0` (no last name).

Comment: Now it only grabs the first two, either the first name and middle initial or the first and last name if there is only two parts, example, first and last name or first middle initial and then last name.  It only grabs the first two.

Comment: @Mark I forgot that Ubound is 1 less since Split is a zero-indexed array. I'll fix it.